# Whatsapp only lets me delete the profile picture [Solved]

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, troubleshooting, miui

Recently, I wanted to change my profile picture on whatsapp for another one, but when I tried to do that, only the option to delete it appeared. This also happens when I want to change the background of a chat or when I want to put a new profile picture for a group.
How can I solve it?

*Miui 6.4.14*
*Whatsapp version: latest*
*Android Marshmallow*

**SOLVED**
After a lot of tine of searching solutions, I found the what was happening: it is a *bug* that only appears in MiUi 6.4.14. This bug has not been solved yet.

Comment: If possible, could you mention the Android version? I don't know much about MIUI, but I guess you're using Android 6.x Marshmallow? If so, did you just upgrade from 5.0 Lollipop? If yes, could you check the permission of WhatsApp: Storage & Camera? Otherwise, I suggest to install another gallery/image picker, such as [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) and try it again. I guess there's a permission issue, or app utility issue (I remember your issue with image uploading on SE app, on Meta.SE)

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh, sorry for not posting the Android version

Comment: Would you please check if you've granted WhatsApp storage access in the permissions page?

Comment: @karanRajpal No, I discovered its a bug of MiUi.